# What to do now? with twig/html drop-down

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down menu,that shows a picture of profile,when I click on it,it drops-down 3 menu
user profile,settings and a logout. When I click on a user profile name,it goes to user profile page.
Here is the problem now when I click on image the drop-down doesn't work,I'm on the user profile page.
Here is some code of base.html.twig:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-5">
   {% if app.user %}
      <li class="nav-item">
         <div class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href=""  id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               <img src="{{ asset('/build/images/user.png') }}">
            </a>

         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('user_profile', {id:app.user.id})}}">{{ app.user.username }}</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Settings</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('logout') }}">Logout</a>
         </div>

      </div>

   </li>

        {% endif %}
        {% if not app.user %}
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('login') }}">Login</a>
           </li>
        {% endif %}
</ul>
```

This is a profile page - profile.html.twig:

```
{% extends('base.html.twig') %}

{% block title %}User {{ app.user.username }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        
        <div>
            <div class="mt-3 ">

                <img class="position-absolute" style="width: 36px;height: 36px" src="{{ asset('/build/images/'~app.user.imageFilename) }}" alt="User image">
                <p class="ml-5 pt-3">User profile: {{ app.user.username }}</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p><span>First Name: </span>{{ app.user.firstName }}</p>
            <p><span>Last Name: </span>{{ app.user.lastName }}</p>
            <p><span>Username: </span>{{ app.user.username }}</p>
            <p><span>User role: </span>{{ app.user.roles[0] }}</p>
        </div>




    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

And now that I'm on a profile page,when I click on image in a navbar I points me to the same profile that I already am on.
Can someone suggest me what to do?
Thank you!

Comment: This is very difficult to help debug without a working snippet. My first approach would be to check the CSS display of your image and link. To experiment, can you make both of them `display: block` or `display: inline-block` in your CSS?

Comment: Has nothing to do with `twig`/`symfony`. Please update your question with the generated code instead of the twig template

Comment: I'm actually not 100% what you're asking here. Are you expecting to go to the profile page if you click on the profile image? In that case, you probably need to add the URL in the `href=""` for the `<a>`-tag that wraps around the profile image, or the browser won't have a clue where you expect the user to be redirected. However, you do say _"when I click on image the drop-down doesn't work"_, but you haven't shown us any code that handles the dropdown (JS?) so we have no idea what should and does/doesn't happen.

Comment: For example: It works like it should on other pages,but when I'm on user profile page,it doesn't work as it should,instead it gives me only a link to the same page. I'm using bootsrtaps drop down classes. On inspect element I see that all links are grey.

Comment: I found out where was a mistake. I added {% block javascripts %} to profile page, and it seems that it overvriten the base.html.twig javascripts. Thanks guys